# Why does using AnimationTimer and setTranslate on a ImageView node create jerky movement?

Tags: java, android, animation, javafx, imageview

My goal is to create a basic 2D game using the Java Fx library. And my subgoal is to create responsive controls and smooth movement of the character. My issue is the player in my game (ImageView node) is a little jerky when I use setTranslate on it. It seems to jerk for every second of continuous movement. Included in this post is an example. I've done research and I've been given conflicting answers... For instance, one person told me to use a WritableImage(because he said it's like BufferedImage), but that didn't seem to solve the jerkyness issue. Any help would be most appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Thank you for the responses. I found out what the issue was. I use a program called f.lux that automatically adjusts screen brightness based on the time of day and it was drastically affecting the game's performance for some reason.

```
package pleasehelp;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PleaseHelp extends Application {

    ImageView imageView;

    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Pane root = new Pane();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 200);

        stage.setTitle("Please Help!");

        stage.setScene(scene);

        Animation animation = new Animation(this);

        Image image = new Image("http://lessonpix.com/drawings/192/100x100/Gray+Square.png");
        imageView = new ImageView();
        imageView.setImage(image);
        root.getChildren().add(imageView);
        animation.start();

        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}

package pleasehelp;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;

public class Animation extends AnimationTimer {

    PleaseHelp please;

    Animation(PleaseHelp please) {
        this.please = please;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(long now) {
        please.imageView.setTranslateX(please.imageView.getTranslateX() + 1);
    }

    public void start() {
        super.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        super.stop();
    }

}
```

Comment: This works fine for me. What platform/OS are you running this on?

Comment: Windows 10, Java 8 131. I don't have the fastest computer: AMD 8350 4ghz, 8 GB, and Radeon R7 200. Let's presume the jerkiness is created by hardware or something outside of the code itself... is there a better way to create movement in Java for a simple 2D game? If there isn't then I guess I'll just go forward with the game. The jerkiness is subtle but I see it. Every .5-1 second or so. Is there a way to change the 60 FPS from AnimationTimer to something higher for testing purposes? Thanks for your response btw.

Comment: Animation timer is probably the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

When writing animations like this it is normally a good idea to compute the next position based on the given time (long now) and not just add a constant value to the current position. That would make your animation more predictive.